# Alternative Captcha Like Services

Tags: captcha

What website that provides captcha like services?

It can be difficult to correct read a Captcha. In some cases the letters are so over stretched that its difficult to discern what the letters are.

Answer (score 0):

[Recapcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) is one of the best. Easy to implement, and hard to bypass